# How to ping a server only once from within a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ping

I want to learn how to write batch scripts and tried to create a script which automatically runs this command in the command line once:

```
ping www.google.de -t
```

and displays the ping, so it would look like this:

```
Reply from XXX.XXX.X.XX: time=30ms
Reply from XXX.XXX.X.XX: time=31ms
Reply from XXX.XXX.X.XX: time=29ms
```

My problem is, that this will result in this when I execute this command as script:

[image: Screenshot showing output on running the batch file.]

My problem is that it will not execute the ping command at all, but just insert the command unlimited times in the console window as its shown in the screenshot.

I just created a new file, wrote `ping www.google.de -t` in it, saved it as `ping.bat` file and executed it with double clicking on it.

So how to write the batch file to start this command only once and display the ping result?

Comment: what do you mean by when I enter this command as a script? If you put it in a batch file, you might consider an @ sign in front of it to not display the command executing.

Comment: Why is your ping running so many times? Can you post your script?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: **DO NOT** name your script `ping.bat` (or any other name that is already used as a command). All it does is repeatedly calling itself.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Enter in a command prompt window `ping /?` and read the short help output after pressing <kbd>RETURN</kbd>. Or take a look on:

- [ping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping) - latest Microsoft documentation for this Windows command
- [ping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490968(v=technet.10)) - Windows XP documentation for this Windows command

Explanation for option `-t` given by Microsoft:

> Specifies ping continue sending echo Request messages to the destination until interrupted. To interrupt and display statistics, press <kbd>CTRL+ENTER</kbd>. To interrupt and quit this command, press <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>.

You may want to use:

```
@%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 www.google.de
```

Or to check first if a server is available:

```
@echo off
set MyServer=Server.MyDomain.de
%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 %MyServer% >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto NoServer

echo %MyServer% is available.
rem Insert commands here, for example one or more net use to connect network drives.
goto :EOF

:NoServer
echo %MyServer% is not available yet.
pause
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 52):

I am sure you must have named the resultant bat file as "ping.bat". If you rename your file to something else say pingXXX.bat. It will definitely work. Try it out.

my batch file contains below code only

```
ping 172.31.29.1 -t
```

with file name as ping.bat
[image]

with file name abc.bat

[image]

Comment: Wow! Any explanation for that? It should be some reserved word, but why that behavior...

Comment: by default, your btach program will check the current directory for any instruction. So if you call ping while a program (your bat file) has this name, then it execute that one instead of the system one.

Answer (score 7):

For bash (OSX) `ping google.com -c 1` (incase search brought you here)

Answer (score 4):

if you want to use the name "ping.bat", a small trick is to use this code:

```
@echo off
cd\ 
ping google.com -t
```

Just add that "cd\" and you are fine... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you are trying but your posted code should work just fine. in case you don't want the command to be displayed, add `@echo off` at starting of your script. If i have the below code in a file named as `test.bat` and run it command prompt as `test.bat` it will work just fine.

```
@echo off
ping www.google.de -t
```

To address your `EDIT:` where the main concern is `ping` command was not recognizable. `ping` command generally will be located under `C:\Windows\System32\` where `C:\` being the root directory. In case, the root directory is different you can get the root directory using `%SystemRoot%` environment variable and can say like

```
%SystemRoot%\Windows\System32\PING.EXE www.google.de -t
```

Another way to see if the command you are trying to run is recognizable or not is using `WHERE` command like below

```
where ping
```

If the command is recognizable; it will output the path like

```
C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE
```

Else will result in error

Comment: I just did what you posted and it didn't work. It just opens a blanc command window and nothing more. In my opinion it has nothing to do with the code but with my cmd.exe, path variables or something else.

Comment: How you are running it? either way, `cd` to the folder where you have saved the `bat` file and then either run from command prompt or directly by double clicking it. It works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I know why, you are using the file name "ping" and you are using the code "ping", it just keeps trying to run itself because its selected directory in where that file is, if you want it to actually ping, put this before the ping command: "cd C:\Windows\system32", the actual file that pings the server is in there!

Comment: ... or just change the name of your file to something other than 'ping'.

Answer (score 1):

From Batch file, ping a ip only once using the following command:
    Ping 192.168.199.10 -n 1

[image]

Comment: how does this add useful information to the accepted (four years old) answer?

Comment: This answers the question from a google search perspective.   I needed to look this up while on my iPhone to tell someone.  Very useful - thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i used Mofi sample, and change some parameters, no you can do -t

@%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n -1 4.2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to think about in this case is, in which directory you are on your computer.
Your command line window shows `C:\users\rei0d\desktop\` as your current directory.

So the only thing you really need to do is: 
Remove the `desktop` by "going up" with the command `cd ..`.

So the complete command would be:

```
cd ..
ping XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -t
```

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything. Since `C:\Windows\System32` is written into the `PATH` variable, `ping` works everywhere (globally). If it's not working for you, then you have to check your `PATH` variable. `echo %PATH%` should return the path mentioned. If not, edit it via `Control Center -> System -> Advanced System settings -> Advanced Tab -> Path variables`.

Answer (score 0):

Having 2 scripts called test.bat and ping.bat in same folder:

Script test.bat contains one line:

```
ping google.com
```

Script ping.bat contains below lines:

```
@echo off
echo Hello!
pause
```

Executing "test.bat" the result on CMD will be:

```
Hello!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why? Because "test.bat" is calling the "ping.bat" ("ping google.com" is interpreted as calling the "ping.bat" script).
Same is happening if script "ping.bat" contains "ping google.com". The script will execute himself in a loop.

> Easy ways to avoid this:
>
> 1. Do not name your script "ping.bat".
> 2. You can name the script as "ping.bat" but inside the script use "ping.exe google.com" instead of "ping google.com".

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file with text "`@%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -t www.google.com`" and save it with extension "`.bat`".
Just click and run it and you will get the result.

[image: Result]

So basically what happens is that we run ping.exe application with parameters '`-t`' and '`www.google.com`' (web-address).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is this

```
Ping -n 1 0.0.0.0
```

But if you want it to be faster than this, this will be your answer

```
Ping -n 1 -l 1 0.0.0.0
```

Note: Replace `0.0.0.0` with your desired IP address

Answer (score 0):

Create a "ping google.bat" file with the following text:

PING.EXE -t -l 666 google.com

"-t" means continuous

"-l 666" means bigger packets (666 bytes each)

Comment: You should mention why this works when the OPs original code does not (it calls ping.exe directly and not the OPs ping.bat recursively). Also, please use back-ticks to format text as code.

Answer (score -1):

Just 
write the command "ping your server IP" without the double quote. save file name as filename.bat and then run the batch file as administrator